# How to make migration from mongodb to sql database

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, migration, apostrophe-cms

I have a project made by apostropheCMS which is using the MongoDB database, and I want to make migration to SQL database which is an oracle database.

Comment: If you want Apostrophe-CMS to use any database other than MongoDB, it would require a rewrite of a large part of Apostrophe, or a custom module to convert from MongoDB to SQL. Please see this question from a couple weeks ago for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808098/apostrophe-cms-running-with-dynamo-db/56810561?r=SearchResults#56810561

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you are just trying to get data out of Apostrophe and not run Apostrophe with a SQL backend:

You can use a tool like `apostrophe-pieces-export` to export whole content groups to files like CSV, TSV, or an Excel doc. That module + documentation is here https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-pieces-export

You will still need to convert that to SQL tables, but at least the data is in a workable format.

I don't think there is the equivalent tool for pages..